# How to fix the Camera at NUMPAD 5 view?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

How can I fix/assign/pin the camera at <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>  position?

I hit <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  and then <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>  and the position/zoom is perfect, But even when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>   it just fix the camera at <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> .

Here is <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  + <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> :
[image]

Here is just <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> :
[image]

Here is the camera: 
[image]

When I hit <kbd>F12</kbd>  it stays like that! 
[image]

I want the <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  + <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> position. If you notice, the avatar stays more rounded.

I want that when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> stays with that angle:
[image]

Comment: Numpad key 5 is for orthographic view, so what you're looking for is to change the camera type to orthographic.

Comment: @stphnl329 thank you very much!!! It works!